# Debugging multithreaded applications

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, winapi

I have an application written in C++ and MFC which is multithreaded running on windows. Occasionally I do get some complaints such as deadlocks or an unhandled exception which is caused because of these threads. Normally I use visual studio (if the problem is reproducible) or else use the WinDbg to analyse the dump files generated. Is there any better way of doing this? Can  I use some other tools to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926/analyzing-multithreaded-programs

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the [Intel Thread Checker](http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/threading/286406.htm) if you have enough budget for it. It does a great job of analysing running programs and alerting you to possible race conditions.

Check out the [demonstration video](http://www.intel.com/software/products/Flash/threading/SPD_nav.swf) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gotten to use it yet, but the [Relacy Race Detector](http://groups.google.com/group/relacy/web) sounds pretty useful for tracking down some classes of threading issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you're deadlocking on CRITICAL_SECTIONs, you can use the [!locks debugger extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2004/02/05/68232.aspx) in WinDbg to find out which thread owns a held lock, then use the kb command to look at that thread's callstack.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreaded system are complex and location of blockages is not made only with appropriate tools. To find the cause of the deadlock you can put a record of the lock / unlock in a table map. When starting an "action lock" you save in the table, when unlock ocours delete the record from the table. At the end of a cycle you can log the state of the table or expect a particular event to do this.
Build this implementation in a dll, so you can use it in other projects too.